# Possible to use Segger J-Link with Intel Quartus to flash FPGA?

Tags: flash, intel-fpga, quartus, j-link

Does anybody know if it's possible to use a Segger J-Link with Intel Quartus to flash an FPGA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK not directly, but through OpenOCD.

You can use `quartus_cpf` to convert the programming file to SVF format, and then set up the J-Link in OpenOCD.

I have a similar setup even for my USB Blaster, because I can program from a machine that doesn't have QuartusII installed that way (also it allows me to avoid the [libudev0-shim](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libudev0) hack to allow Quartus's `jtagd` to find the device).

My [build script](https://gitlab.com/GyrosGeier/pcie-test/-/blob/main/fpga/build.sh) generates the SVF with

```
quartus_cpf \
    --convert \
    --frequency=10MHz \
    --voltage=3.3V \
    --operation=p \
    output_files/pcie_test.sof \
    output_files/pcie_test.svf
```

and I send it to the device with

```
openocd \
    -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/altera-usb-blaster.cfg \
    -c init \
    -c 'svf pcie_test.svf' \
    -c exit
```

You would probably use one of the j-link scripts for the initial setup. If you have more devices on the same scan chain, either build a CDF file in the QuartusII Programmer and pass that to `quartus_cpf`, or tell it the sum of the IR lengths before and after your device.

For details on QuartusII command line tools, see the [scripting reference](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/manual/tclscriptrefmnl.pdf).

Comment: Thanks very much for the information!  I'm still new to a lot of this but you gave me a lot of good information to start looking at.